# EclipseLink error when persisting an entity ( id null )

Tags: ejb, eclipselink, jpql

Stacktrace 1: Error coming from method "submitTicket" line 74 which is: `em.persist(bean);`

```
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.creer(Unknown Source)
    at projet.helpdesk.dao.__EJB31_Generated__TicketDao__Intf____Bean__.creer(Unknown Source)
    at projet.helpdesk.form.CreationTicketForm.soumettreTicket(CreationTicketForm.java:74)
```

Stacktrace 2:

```
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01502: index 'BDD2.TICKETS_PK' or partition of such index is in unusable state

Error Code: 1502
Call: INSERT INTO Tickets (ID_TICKET, DATE_ENVOI, DATE_FERMETURE, DESCRIPTION, ETAT, ID_EMPLOYE, ID_TECHNICIEN, PRIORITE, SUJET) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [9 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(projet.helpdesk.beans.Ticket@1d796c68)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
```

Mentionining that the ORA-1502 ERROR started showing after i restarted my PC and before that it was the ORA-0001 ERROR which describes the duplicated values problem.

When i'm inserting the bean through `em.persist(bean);` the Primary key aka id_ticket is set to null and it is a Trigger used in Oracle that increments the value.

Comment: I don't think this error has anything to do with ejb or java - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01502_index_string_string_or_partition_of_such_index_is_in_usable_state.htm

Comment: i've already spent two hours reading the ORA ERRORS docs, thanks anyway i guess i should not rely on ORACLE tiggers to generate primary keys as long as it doesnt work for me, i will try to learn how to generate PKeys through JPQL sequences.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Java Persistence Query Language seems to generate 0 for Primary keys that don't have values when inserted instead of sending them as null objects, so i just Changed the Trigger in ORACLE that generates the primary key, as follows:

```
create or replace trigger "BI_TICKETS"   
  before insert on "TICKETS"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."ID_TICKET" is null or :NEW."ID_TICKET"=0 then 
    select "TICKETS_SEQ".nextval into :NEW."ID_TICKET" from dual; 
  end if; 
end; 
​
```

Added the `:NEW."ID_TICKET"= 0` to the condition, and it's done.